# SLComposeViewController get crash in ios8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, slcomposeviewcontroller

```
SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        controller.view.hidden = YES;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:^{
            [controller.view endEditing:YES];
        }];
```

This code working fine in iOS6 & iOS7 but it get crash in iOS 8:

```
**2014-09-03 08:48:19.545 [1254:248164] Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 6.)
2014-09-03 08:48:19.558[1254:248164] Discovered extensions: {(
 <NSExtension: 0x17013eaa0> {id = com.apple.share.SinaWeibo.post},
 <NSExtension: 0x17013ee60> {id = com.apple.share.Facebook.post},
 <NSExtension: 0x17013ebe0> {id = com.apple.share.Twitter.post},
 <NSExtension: 0x17013f400> {id = com.apple.share.TencentWeibo.post},
 <NSExtension: 0x17013e780> {id = com.apple.share.Vimeo.post},
 <NSExtension: 0x17013e6e0> {id = com.apple.share.Flickr.post},
 <NSExtension: 0x17013e640> {id = com.apple.mobileslideshow.StreamShareService}
)} for attributes: {
 NSExtensionPointName = "com.apple.share-services";
}**
```

Get error message for :: `**LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called**`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get solution for that issue in iOS8, problem in  `controller.view.hidden = YES;`, In iOS8 default settings alert view hided in view, i use this simple code for iOS7 & iOS8

```
if (!SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
        controller.view.hidden = YES;
else
    controller.view.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is not the solution, you need to upgrade the facebook version for iOS8 and Xcode 6.0.1, which will work on both iOS7 and iOS8+.**